# Failed to boot JBoss:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jboss, nullpointerexception

I'm running jboss using command line its showing error as Failed to boot JBoss:java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory.create  Source(StaticProfileFa
ctory.java:313)
    at    org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory.create ProfileMetaData(Static
ProfileFactory.java:270)
    at   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory.createApplicationProfile(Sta
ticProfileFactory.java:245)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory.createApplicationProfiles(St
aticProfileFactory.java:232)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory.createProfileMetaData(Static
ProfileFactory.java:214)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractBootstrapProfileFactory.createProfiles(Ab
stractBootstrapProfileFactory.java:90)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:2
60)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
06:07:01,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
06:07:01,744 WARN  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Error deactivating profile: ProfileKey@eba82b[domain=default, ser
ver=default, name=default]
org.jboss.profileservice.spi.NoSuchProfileException: No active profile for: ProfileKey@eba82b[domain=default,
server=default, name=default]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.deactivateProfile(Abstract
ProfileService.java:391)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.shutdown(ProfileServiceBootstrap.jav
a:327)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.shutdownServer(AbstractServerImpl.java:571)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl$ShutdownHook.run(AbstractServerImpl.java:909)
06:07:01,747 WARN  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Error unregistering profile: ProfileKey@eba82b[domain=default,   se
rver=default, name=default]
org.jboss.profileservice.spi.NoSuchProfileException: No such profile: ProfileKey@eba82b[domain=default, server
=default, name=default]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.getProfile(AbstractProfile
Service.java:181)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.shutdown(ProfileServiceBootstrap.jav
a:336)
    at          org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.shutdownServer(AbstractServerImpl.java:571)        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl$ShutdownHook.run(AbstractServerImpl.java:909)
06:07:02,085 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
Shutdown complete
 Halting VM
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can anybody guide me to resolve this issue, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***org.jboss.profileservice.spi.NoSuchProfileException*** might be the reason of this NPE. Make sure that you have the 'default' domain present - I assume that you're tring to launch JBoss 5, is that correct?